# Event bubbling up the entire HTML and registering all the events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, mouseevent

I've two components where I'm using event propogation to define custom animation. In the 1st component,the event Propogation works fine and is contained within the element. In component2, I'm listening to onMouseOver event, and the event is being registered wherever I move the mouse on the HTML page.
Here's the code.

1st Component

```
 const handleMouse = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.innerText);
  };
 useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("pointermove", handleMousemove);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("pointermove", handleMousemove);
    };
  }, []);


 <h1 onMouseOver={handleMouse} className="text-white text-6xl">
            Hello
 </h1>
```

Component-2(The event is registered everywhere within the HTML page, even in different Components)

```
const handleMouse = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();

 
console.log(event.target.innerText);
}
 useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("pointermove", handleMousemove);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("pointermove", handleMousemove);
    };
  }, []);


<h1
onMouseOver={handleMouse}
className="hover:text-rose-700 transition-all duration-500 cursor-default">
Modern Responsive Websites
</h1>
```

I tried event.preventDefault(), event.stopPropagation() and event.stopImmediatePropagation individually and combined. Nothing is working.
What am I doing wrong?

Here is the entire code (this is component 2)

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const New = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("Hello");
  const handleMouse = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    let iterations = 0;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      event.target.innerText = event.target.innerText
        .split("")
        .map((ele, i, ar) => {
          if (i < iterations) {
            return value[i];
          }
          return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)];
        })
        .join("");
      if (iterations >= 5) clearInterval(interval);
      iterations += 1;
    }, 60);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouse);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouse);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 onMouseOver={handleMouse} className="text-white text-6xl">
        Hello
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default New;
```

Component 1 works fine and whenever I get the mouse over the h1 element, it registers and does the work, but with the inclusion of 2nd component, the event is being registered on the whole HTML page(where ever I move the mouse the event triggers).

Comment: You have just omitted cruical parts of the JSX in the code and provided 2 identical components. So how would anyone help?

Comment: As of the lack of code information, my guess would be your Component2 is being rendered nested inside some elements and you'd have to call propagation methods on these parents, otherwise move Component2 up the ladder, if that's possible.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the incomplete code. The entire code is unnecessary however, I still have updated the code. Pls do tell me what I'm doing wrong